# How to make a SPARQL query that counts unique nodes within the OPTIONAL clause

Tags: sparql

I'd like to make a SPARQL query that counts unique nodes within and without an OPTIONAL clause as follows:

```
SELECT (count(?o) AS ?numA) (count(DISTINCT ?o) AS ?numD) (count(?r) AS ?numO) ?UniqueCountOf_o_within_the_OPTIONAL_clause
WHERE {
  ?i ex:predicate ?o.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?o rdf:type ?r.
  }
}
```

Values of numA, numD, and numO can be obtained properly, but I don't have any idea of getting the unique count of ?o within the OPTIONAL clause. Is there any way of making a query, or should I separate it into two queries?

Thanks.

Comment: you're already computing all count values, so what is the "unique count of ?o" ? Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy the values of ?o in the OPTIONAL clause into a new variable ?o2 and then count the number of distinct values on ?o2.

```
SELECT (count(?o) AS ?numA) (count(DISTINCT ?o) AS ?numD) (count(?r) AS ?numO) (count(DISTINCT ?o2) AS ?numX) WHERE {
  ?i ex:predicate ?o.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?o rdf:type ?r.
    BIND (?o AS ?o2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I tried the bind, but it failed at that time, now it works on Apache Jena Fuseki 3.14.0. I don't know why...